# How to display photos in gridview or imagegallery in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, gridview

I have different number of photos in tableview custom cell.Now i want to display that photos
on next page.4 photos per line.how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UIScrollView` for this...

Each item in your grid is a `UIImageView` which you add as subviews to your `UIScrollView`.

The following code can be insterted in `viewDidLoad` inside your view controller and assumes that you have setup your UISCrollView in interface builder, otherwise you would need to allocate your scroll view inside `viewDidLoad`.

The code will add a variable number of image items to a UIScrollView with 4 columns.

```
UIImageView *imageView = nil;

//The x and y view location coordinates for your menu items 
int x = 0, y = 0;

//The number of images you want 
int numOfItemsToAdd = 10; 

//The height and width of your images are the screen width devided by the number of columns 
int imageHeight = 320/4, imageWidth = 320/4; 

int numberOfColumns = 4; 

//The content seize needs to refelect the number of items that will be added
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, imageHeight*numOfItemsToAdd];
for(int i=0; i<numOfItemsToAdd; i++){
    if(i%numberOfColumns == 0){//% the number of columns you want
        x = 0;
        if(i!=0)
            y += imageHeight;  
    }else{
        x = imageHeight;  
    }
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, imageWidth, imageHeight)];

    //set the center of the image in the scrollviews coordinate system 
    imageView.center = CGPointMake(x, y); 

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_photo.png"]; 

    //Finaly add the image to the scorll view
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: thnx.i  also implement the same solution by myself

Comment: How do you handle the selection of items ?