# Grid view of images( loaded from url)

Tags: iphone, ios, gridview

i have created a code for grid view in xcode and now i want to load multiple images into the grid view .how to load multiple images in grid view and these images should be loaded from url   also.
help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562211/how-to-display-photos-in-gridview-or-imagegallery-in-iphone/5562228#5562228     but i implemented the same in viewdidload but not working.take a look and how to implement into uiview

Answer (score 0):

How about after you load the images from the web(try using SDWebImage search this in the net) after you loaded you can save it an NsDocumentDirectory after saving load it inside a scrollview thumbnail(open source codes: FGallery, GMGridView.. Search it in github). (sorry for the format im using iPhone)

Comment: hi can u give me code of grid view .for now just from start itself.how to code for grid view

Comment: code into the below link i used it --> into the view did load but not even a single row is working..or else can u give me ur email id i will mail u my code ..u can check there and help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562211/how-to-display-photos-in-gridview-or-imagegallery-in-iphone/5562228#5562228

Comment: my email add is there. but here supermanballer810506@gmail.com